# Creating a GE through Env. Hub results in a EE

Tags: group-edition, environment-hub

I'm trying to create a Group Edition organization through the new Environment Hub feature, and even though I'm explicitly requesting for a GE, it creates an Enterprise Edition for me. What is the reason for that? How may I create a Group Edition organization?

[image: Screen shot]

Comment: You would log a case to SFDC support. Same thing happening for me as well.

Comment: Ok, lets try that too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue

https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000008ZFwAAM

The work around:

> Repro
>
> 1. In an Environment Hub org, go to "Environment Hub" tab
> 2. click "Create Organization", select "Test/Demo" for purpose, then leave the default "Group Edition" as is to create a GE org
> 3. Enter other needed info and click "Create"
> 4. Org is created and it is an EE org
>
> Workaround
>
> As a workaround, in step 2, select any other value for "Edition"
>   first(e.g., partner group), then switch back to "Group Edition", the
>   org will be created as GE.